# How to use assert_raises to catch SystemExit exception

Tags: python, testing, assert, nose

I have code which I want to test:

```
from random import randint

class End(object):
          def __init__(self):
             self.quips=['You dead', 'You broke everything you can','You turn you head off']

          def play(self):
                print self.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
                sys.exit(1)
```

How can I check whether it exits or not using accept_raises?

```
def test_End():
    end=End().play()
    assert_raises(what should I put here)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `@raises` decorator

```
from nose.tools import raises

@raises(SystemExit)
def test_End():
    end=End().play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `SystemExit` exception in [assertRaises](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
    End().play()
```

or patch `sys.exit` via [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/):

```
with patch.object(sys, 'exit') as mock_method:
    End().play()
    self.assertTrue(mock_method.called)
```

Comment: This is only available using the python unittest framework. It doesn't look like OP is using that here. You can import this from `nose.tools` though

Comment: @Greg yup, but the OP doesn't use `nose` either :)